# Why does the peak power change with the spectrum analyzer's span?

Tags: rf, microwave, spectrum-analyzer

Consider a continuous wave signal being displayed on a spectrum analyzer at f=5GHz. It's a single peak. When I put marker on the peak it shows me the peak measured power. Now when I decrease the span of the instrument from 10MHz to, lets say, 1MHz, the measured peak power is increased. Can someone explain why this is so?

I am sure it has something to do with the RBW of the instrument. Also if the power changes with span, if I just need to measure the peak power should I be using zero span mode?

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/150609/9612) looks like it might be related; can you take a brief look? (not marking as a duplicate because I don't know enough about spectrum analyzers to know whether it is in fact a dupe)

Comment: By how much did the measured power increase when you lowered the resolution bandwidth to 1 MHz?

Comment: @Andyaka I do not remember exactly but it was something like 0.6dBm